# Delete a .csv file after import from a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rake

I'm able to import my .csv file from my server but now i simply want to delete it after the import occurs.  I have all of the code in a rake task and I'm trying to delete the incidents.csv file after the task is completed.  Here is my code.

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'


namespace :import_incidents_csv do

task :create_incidents => :environment do
    puts "Import Incidents"

    #csv_text = File.read('/Users/Ben/Sites/ror/LFD/incidents.csv', :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8')
    csv_text = open("http://www.##########.com/###########/incidents.csv") {|f| f.read}
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)

    @incident_id_array = []
    @report_nr_array = []
    csv.each do |row|
        row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
        Incident.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
        @incident_id_array << Incident.last.id
        @report_nr_array << Incident.last.report_nr
    end

    #------This combines the incidents array and the report_nr array into a hash

    @report_incident_hash = {}
    @report_nr_array.each_with_index do |value, index|
        @report_incident_hash[value] = @incident_id_array[index]
    end
    #puts @report_incident_hash

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can ssh to the server, try the [net/ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) gem and to run a 'rm' command